GitLab pipeline triggers without respecting rules
I have written a CI code to trigger my Gitlab pipeline only when the content of the file boot.sh is changed. However, I realized that the pipeline does not respect the set rule, instead it triggers everytime a commit is made or when a new branch is created in the repository. The workspace tree structure looks is below
----service/new/new_service.yml
    |          /boot.sh 
    |
    |
    .gitlab-ci.yml

The gitlab-ci is linked to the yml file in the service/new/new_service.yml file
include: 
  - local: 'service/new/new_service.yml'

The content of the new_service.yml  file is as seen below
build-job:
  variables:
    Setup_DIR: 'service/new/boot.sh'
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Boot file has been changed from test pipeline again "
  rules:
      changes:
        paths:
          - $Setup_DIR

I'll appreciate if someone that has gone through similar issue in the past or have good knowledge about Gitlab pipeline can come to my aid.

This is documented in the gitlab rules:changes https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

From the docs You can use rules: changes with other pipeline types, but rules: changes always evaluates to true for new branch pipelines or when there is no Git push event. Pipelines like tag pipelines, scheduled pipelines, and manual pipelines, all do not have a Git push event associated with them. In these cases, use rules: changes: compare_to to specify the branch to compare against.

Yo7 might want to use this design pattern https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschangescompare_to

@ChrisDoyle, got it sorted. Thanks
